# Checking for TLS between client and server

Tags: tls

There is a website with no HTTPS certificate on it and i have checked it is transmitting username password in clear text.

I scanned the system and application using IBM Appscan and Nexpose

IBM Appscan (Web Vulnerability Scanner) detects no HTTPS which i can confirm by opening link on browser

Nepose (Vulnerability Scanning tool) detected that self signed certificate is implemented on port 443 it tried to open webpage with port https://url:443 but page redirects to normal http (no certificate)
nexpose also detects TLS 1.0 is implemented

Application vendor says that on back end TLS is implemented

How can i verify that TLS is implemented on back end ? Nexpose confimred it but is there any other way

Comment: And what is this question about? You stated it is transmitting plain text. Then?

Comment: do you get https as SERVICE in **nmap -sS -Pn -p443 youserver** ?

Comment: which server is used ? did you get redirected when you visit **https://weburl:443/**?

Comment: Hi Guys,

i just tried https://full link it is now opened in HTTPS with certificate thus it means site support both https and http ?

nmap result 

Port 443
State Filterd
Service HTTPS
System is UP

Answer (score 2):

Use OpenSSL to attempt to connect and dump the certificate (if any).

```
openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port>
```

If it fails to connect, TLS isn't implemented. If it connects, then you'll get the certificate and you can check what it looks like.